# inherit parent class arguments in child class constructor for python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop

I am writing test cases by mocking some external api calls using python. I have a parent class that takes external api clients as arguments that has the url information. Then I am inheriting some of the methods in Child class from the parent class. When I am mocking the child class methods, I am passing a mock url instead of the actual url. Unfortunately, the child class takes the url that has been passed in the parent class. When I just mock the parent class, the assertion depends on the mock url that I am passing.

Parent class

```
class Parent:
   def __init__(self, id:str, item:str, item_client = ClientSettings(settings.config.api_url)):
      self.id = id
      self.item = item
      self.item_client = item_client

   async def main_method_in_parent(self):
      order_details = self.item_client.get_item_details(self.id)
      get_order_details = order_details["response"]["payload"]["orders"]["details"]
```

Child Class

```
class Child(Parent):
   def __init__(self, id:str, item:str, status:str = None):
       super().__init__(id, item)
       self.status = status

   async def method_in_child(self):
      await self.main_method_in_parent()
      order_status = self.item_client.get_order_status(self.status)
      get_status = order_status["response"]["result"]["orders"]["details"]["status"]
```

Test Case

```
mock_json = {
   "response": {
      "payload": {
         "orders": {
            "details": "order_name",
            "status": "shipped"
         }
      }
   }
}
class TestParent(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_parent_child(self):
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      mock_client_api = ClientSettings("dummy_url")
      mock_client_api.get_item_details = MagicMock(return_value=async_return(mock_json))
      mock_client_api.get_order_status = MagicMock(return_value=async_return(mock_json))

      test_parent = Parent(id="3dcff3", item="some_item", item_client=mock_client_api)
      test_child = Child(test_parent, status="shipped")

      loop.run_until_complete(test_child.method_in_parent())
      loop.run_until_complete(test_child.method_in_child())

      assert get_order_details == "order_name"
      assert get_status == "shipped"

      loop.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In the above described case, the first assertion from parent class passes, but the second assertion (get_status) fails with an error

> AttributeError: 'ClientConnectorError' object has no attribute 'get'

After debugging, I figured out that my parent class is taking the dummy api url that I provided while mocking, but the child class somehow takes the actual api url from the parent class. Am I missing anything?

Comment: How are you able to instantiate a `Child` with only 2 parameters?

Comment: @quamrana are you asking about the test method?

Comment: Yes, in `test_parent_child(self)`

Comment: As per my understanding, when I do test_child = Child(test_parent, status="shipped"), it inherits the params from the parent class right?

Comment: No, `Child` has it's own `__init__()` method. You should be getting an error.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.